# Read Data From One Controller To Another

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I've two controllers and two views in `ASP.NET MVC` project. My requirement is to pass data from one controller to another on **ng-click** that should reflect in another view (As well from another controller). Simple! I know, it could be done using service but I was preferring for testing purpose `$broadcast` and `$on`. So I tried the following:

```
app.controller('FirstController', function ($rootScope, $scope, productService) {
    $scope.showData = function (m) { //This is the event on which I'll get data in another controller as well in another view 
    alert(m); //This works and gets a name from the first view

    $rootScope.$broadcast('sample', $scope.m); //This is what I am using to deliver in another controller
    }
});

app.controller('SecondController', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.$on('sample', function (events, d) {
    alert(d);
})
```

In another view, I used something like this:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="SecondController">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#"> Product {{ m }}</a></li>            
   </ul>
</div>
```

Actually I am doing this all for demo purpose. But unfortunately, the above doesn't work. Am I missing something?

**Update 1 -** See the updated code:

```
app.controller('FirstController', function ($rootScope, $scope, productService) {
    $scope.showData = function (m) { //This is the event on which I'll get data in another controller as well in another view 
    alert(m); //This works and gets a name from the first view

      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.$broadcast('sample', m);
    });
  }
});

app.controller('SecondController', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.$on('sample', function (events, d) {
    alert(d);
})
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "doesn't work"? Is the `$scope.$on` function in `SecondController` being called and `d` isn't what you expect it to be, or is not even being called?

Comment: @james00794 actually I am unable to see the passed data in the second controller.

Comment: So the `alert(m)` works, but does `alert($scope.m)` work within `FirstController`? Why are you passing `$scope.m` to the `$scope.$broadcast` call instead of just `m`?

Comment: I already tried that @james00794. That even doesn't work.

Comment: Can you verify that the `$scope.$on` handler is called in `SecondController`?

Comment: Thanks a lot and it worked @james00794.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario it will not work in  one case:

You call `$rootScope.$broadcast('sample', $scope.m);` before 
`$scope.$on()` is registered to listen on `'sample` event a.e. before   `SecondController` is created.

If you know that `SecondController` is created , you can wrap `$rootScope.$broadcast('sample', $scope.m);` with `$timeout`. a.e.:

```
$timeout(function(){
  $rootScope.$broadcast('sample', $scope.m); 
});
```

In this case `$broadcast` execution will be moved to end of events queue a.e. before next digest cycle that will be guarantee that Second Controller has been created and `$scope.$on()` is registered.

Comment: I tried your code using $timeout @Maxim Shoustin but still unable to pass data. See my updated post.

Comment: @AT-2017 that mean, you dont show ng-controller="SecondController" view when call $broadcast :)

Comment: I've already defined the `ng-controller` in the second view but don't konw actually why it's happening @Maxim Shoustin.

Comment: @AT-2017 add log as 1st row in `app.controller('SecondController', function ($scope) {}` be sure its called

Comment: Thanks a lot and finally worked @Maxim Shoustin. IMO, in some cases, `AngularJs` becomes really bothering :D

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear how you are using the second view & controller. Is it somewhere within the template that `FirstController` is assigned to? Seeing the template assigned to `FirstController` would help clarify. In any case, I've attached a simple plunker which shows how you can broadcast an event from a button click to a second controller.

https://plnkr.co/edit/KzNftVAYwPuCvsnflIz